# How can I code an efficient mobile site like gmail's?

Tags: mobile-website

My web site has a different mobile version that's suited for iPhone/Android devices. The problem, however, seems to be in the site's performance. It's really slow and heavy, even though I'm not loading any images.

On the other hand, when I use Gmail's or YouTube's mobile version, they're so fast they almost perform like a native mobile application.

How do they do that?

Your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Is the mobile version a completely different application, or is it the same desktop website but served with different stylesheets? Take a look at how many http requests there are. You say there are no images but what about javascript and css and other resources such as fonts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my comment. Also, if the slowness you perceive is when interacting with the site it could be that it lacks the ability to accept touch events. On mobile web, if you have not wired up the UI for js touch events the experience will seem slower because the device browser has to fall back to standard click and other mouseevents which are not optimal. Frameworks such as mootools and jquerymobile/jqtouch have these events baked in. Take a look at the mootools solution which has quite a good write up: http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-touch

Answer (score 1):

They probably making use of local storage http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/
Are your pages too large? Try to use gzip and/or reduce output
Your server's connection speed may also be responsible of slowness

Answer (score 0):

Well, You don't need to include any javascript framework to make it fast clickable.

By implementing some JavaScript you can achieve that. Google has released a solution for that

https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons

This will allow visitor to interact with application native way. From Android 4 (as far as I remember) version by setting viewport meta tag the browser will automatically apply the fast click functionality.

For the animation issue always use Hardware accelerated animation with a fall back for older mobile browser. Using hardware accelerated animation it will make your application smooth as silk.

Follow this guideline and you can make your application as fast as gmail / youtube mobile version.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your webapp is consuming too much RAM. Don't use so many libraries and don't attach so many event handlers.